# Does the sum of digits squared of a number when we keep on doing it lead to a single digit number?

Tags: number-theory

When we add the digits of number for eg $2478125$
$$2+4+7+8+1+2+5=29;\\
2+9=11;\\
1+1=2$$
and when we square the digits and add them following this rule
$$2^2+4^2+7^2+8^2+1^2+2^2+5^2=163;\\
1^2+6^2+3^2=46; \\
4^2+6^2=52;\\
5^2+2^2=29;\\
2^2+9^2=85;$$and this goes on, so the question is 
will it ever reach a single digit.And what is the proof of it.

Comment: Great question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmm... If $N$ has $k$ digits the sum of the squares, lets call is $s(N)$ is less than or equal to $81k$ which has at most $\lceil \log_{10} k + \log_{10} 81 \rceil $ digits.  Which means if $N$ has four or more digits $s(N) < N$ so we only need to check $3$ digit or fewer as all cases will reduce to these.

If $N$ has 3 digits or fewer $s(N) \le 3*81 = 241$ so we only need to check for values less or equal to $241$ which in turn must yield a result less than or equal to $16 + 81+81 = 178$ which will yield a result less than or equal to $1 + 49 + 81 = 131$ which yields a result less than or equal to $1 + 9 + 81 = 91$

Now there are only so many results to $a^2 + b^2$   Actually $45$ of them.

So let's check $(0,0)...(9,9)$

$(0,1):S(0) = 0$ stabilizes.

$(0,1):S(1) = 1$ stabilizes.

$(0,2):4 \rightarrow 16\rightarrow 37 \rightarrow 58 \rightarrow 89  \rightarrow 145 \rightarrow 1+16+25=42\rightarrow 20 \rightarrow 4$ is an infinite loop.

We will not need to check $(0,4),(1,6),(2,4),(3,7)(5,8)(8,9)$

$(0,3):9 \rightarrow 81 \rightarrow 65 \rightarrow 61 \rightarrow 37$ becomes the loop above.

We will not need to check $(1,8),(5,6)$

$(0,5):25 \rightarrow 29\rightarrow 85\rightarrow S(58)$ so is loop above

We will not need to check $(2,5),(2,9)$

$(0,6):36 \rightarrow 45 \rightarrow 34\rightarrow 25$ is loop above

We will not need to check $(3,5)(3,6)(4,5)$

$(0,7):49 \rightarrow 97 \rightarrow 130 \rightarrow 10\rightarrow 1$ stabilizes

We will not need to check $(1,3),(7,9)$

$(0,8):64 \rightarrow 52 \rightarrow S(25)$ so loops

We will not need to check $(4,6)$

$(0,9):81\rightarrow 92 \rightarrow S(29)$ so loops.

We will not need to check $(1,8)$

So what *do* we need to check?

Well, I did it a little inefficiently:

Most of the sums will be repeats.  $1+1 =2 \rightarrow 4$; $1+4=5\rightarrow 25$;$1+9=10;$ $1+16=17\rightarrow 50\rightarrow 25;$ $1+ 25=26\rightarrow 40=S(4);$ $1+36=37;$ $1+49=50$; $1+64=65$; $1+81=82\rightarrow 68 \rightarrow 100\rightarrow 1$;

$4+4=8\rightarrow 64$; $4+9=13\rightarrow 10;$ $4+25=29$; $4+36=40$; $4+49=53\rightarrow 34$; $4+64=68$; $4+81=85$;

$9+9 = 18\rightarrow S(81)$;$9+16=25$; $9+25=34$; $9+36=45\rightarrow 41\rightarrow 17$;$9+49=58$; $9+64=73\rightarrow 58$; $9+81=90\rightarrow 81$.

$16+16 = 32\rightarrow 13\rightarrow 10$; $16+25=41$; $16+36=52$; $16+49=65$; $16+64=80\rightarrow 64$; $16+81=97$;

$25+25=50$; $25+36=61\rightarrow 37;$$25+49=74\rightarrow 65$; $25+64=89$;$25+81=106\rightarrow 37$;

$49 + 49 = 98\rightarrow S(89$; $49+64=113\rightarrow 11\rightarrow 2$; $49+81=130$;

$64+64 = 128\rightarrow 69 \rightarrow 97$; $64+ 81= 145$; $81+81= 162 = 41$.

All other numbers will fall into one of those patterns:

a) eventually stabilize at $1$.

b) fall into the loop $4 \rightarrow...... \rightarrow 20 \rightarrow 4 ...$.

=====

Actually, we work down instead of up we can use the logic: if $N > S(N)$ or $N = ab > ba$ or one of the digits of $N$ is zero, we can defer evaluating untill the lower value we can do:

$99:\rightarrow 81 + 81 + 162 \rightarrow 41$ defer:

$89: \rightarrow 64 + 81 = 145\rightarrow 42$ defer:

$88: \rightarrow 64+64 = 128 \rightarrow 1+4+64$ defer:

$79: \rightarrow 81 + 49 = 130$ defer:

$78: \rightarrow 64 + 49 =113 \rightarrow 11$ defer:

$77: \rightarrow 49 + 49 = 98\equiv 89$ still defer:

$69:\rightarrow 36 + 81 = 117 = 51$ defer:

$68: \rightarrow 36 + 64 = 100$ defer (but c'mmon, ,It's 1)

$67: \rightarrow 36+49=85\equiv 58$ defer:

$66: \rightarrow 72\equiv 27 $ defer:

$59: \rightarrow 25+81 = 106$ defer:

$58: \rightarrow 25 + 64 = 89$ continue to defer

$57\rightarrow 25 + 49 = 74\equiv 47$ defer

$56\rightarrow 25+ 36 = 61 \equiv 16$ defer

$55\rightarrow 25+25=50$ defer

$49: \rightarrow 16 + 81 = 97\equiv 79$ continue to defer

$48:\rightarrow 16 + 64 = 80$ defer

$47: \rightarrow 16+49= 65\equiv 56$ continue to defer

$46: \rightarrow 16 + 36=52\equiv 25$ defer

$45: \rightarrow 16 + 25 = 14\equiv 14$ defer

$44: \rightarrow 32$ defer

$39:\rightarrow 90$ defer

$38:\rightarrow 9 + 64 =73\equiv 37$ defer

$37:\rightarrow 9 + 49= 58 \rightarrow 89$ continue to defer(until 24)

$36: \rightarrow 9 + 36 = 45$ defer til 14$

$35: \rightarrow 9 + 25=34$ defer

$34: \rightarrow 25$ defer

$33: \rightarrow 18$ defer

$29: \rightarrow 4+ 81 = 85$ defer til 24

$28: \rightarrow 4 + 64 = 68 \rightarrow 100$ defer til 1

$27:\rightarrow 4+ 49 = 53\rightarrow 34$ defer to 25

$26:\rightarrow 4+36 = 40$ defer

$25 :\rightarrow 4+25= 29$ defer to 24

$24: 4+ 16 = 2$ defer til 2$

$23: 4+9 = 13$ defer

$22\rightarrow 8$ defer

$19: \rightarrow 82$ defer til 1

$18: \rightarrow 65$ defer til 16

$17: \rightarrow 50$ defer

$16: \rightarrow 37$ defer til 2

$15: \rightarrow 26$ defer til 4

$14:\rightarrow 17$ defer til 5$

$13: \rightarrow 10 $ defer til 1$

$12: $ defer till 5

$11$ defer til 2

$9:\rightarrow 81$ defer til 2

$8: \rightarrow 64$ defer til 2

$7: \rightarrow 49$ defer til 1

$6:\rightarrow 36$ deftil 5

$5: \rightarrow 25 $ defer til 2

$4: \rightarrow 16$ defer til 2$

$3: \rightarrow 9 $ defer til 2$

**$2\rightarrow  4\rightarrow 16\rightarrow \rightarrow 58 \rightarrow 89 \rightarrow 145 \rightarrow 42 \rightarrow 20 \rightarrow 4$ infinite loop**

**$1 \rightarrow 1$ stabilizes**

Answer (score 1):

The answer is yes, it's the subject of this year's french olympiads : for one or two digits numbers, you prove by hand (or computer) verification that the resulting sequence is either stationnary at $1$, or loops indefinitely from $4$ to $16$, $37$, $58$, $89$, $145$, $42$, $20$, $4$ and so on.

Then you prove it for 3 digits numbers (again by hand verification), and finally, prove that if $x$ has $p\ge4$ digits, then $f(x)$ has at most $p-1$ digits.

There may be smarter solutions for $2$ and $3$ digits numbers, for example construct a graph, because the order of digits is irrelevant.

Comment: OK, I am glad someone did this because I was just doing all the 2-digit numbers by hand (which is doable) but wasn't looking forward to doing the 3-digit ones! :)

Comment: You can reduce the numbers to check a lot fewer and doing a single loop will concurrently check a dozen or so.

Comment: Only 45 you have to check.  And when you check the first 2 or the you simultaneously check all but four or five.